# Use an Access 2010 form based on 1 table to enter data in a linked table

Tags: ms-access

First of all, I am a total NOOB! I am trying to make an Access DB for handling orders through an entire process.  As such, I have created tables based on each of the individual processes. The order data, which holds only the basic information is in tblCurrentOrders.  Each of the other processes is linked to tblCurrentOrders by the OrderNumber field.  The first step of the process is due date information is entered in the tblPlanner table.  Obviously, until data is entered in tblPlanner, no OrderNumber exists (this will hold true for the other tables, too, if I ever get that far).

I want to create a form based tblCurrentOrders that shows only the records without corresponding entries in tblPlanner (new orders) and then I want to be able to enter the tblPlanner info in a subform.  I have tried making a form based on tblCurrentOrders with a subform based on tblPlanner, but I can't figure out how to only display new orders.  I also tried basing the form on a query that only showed new orders, but I don't know how to make the subform based on tblPlanner to work.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the easiest way to link the tables would be to create your OrderNumber in the tblPlanner when you start a new order.  Then add a flag and timestamp as to whether it's "released" yet.

**EDIT**

Since you provide a little bit more detail, I'll edit my response to more closely align for your desired approach.

Creating a "New Order" is a multi-step process.  So it's usually best to create a Command Button on a form that calls VBA code.  This will allow you to control each step and make sure it's correct.

**Step A: First you want to:**

1) Create a Control Form (if you haven't already) that allows you to put Command Buttons which will launch different VBA code or open different display Forms.

2) On the Control Form, create a List Box that allows you to select an existing OrderNumber.

3) On the Control Form, create a Command Button to open an Order Form which uses the selected List Box OrderNumber.  When that Order Form opens, it will populate with the tblCurrentOrders data for that OrderNumber and also populate the subform with tblPlanner data.  (As long as you have them linked properly.)

4) On the Control Form, create a Command Button to open the Order Form with a set of records which are "New Orders" only.  See the more detailed process below in Step C.

5) On the Control Form, create a Command Button to Launch VBA code that will create a "New Order".  This is a multi step process detailed below in Step B.

6) Create any other buttons or controls that allow you to monitor or advance your "Order" along the way to completion.  (This is a ton of work to get all the pieces in place.)

**Step B: When you press the Command Button to create a "New Order" you want to create VBA code that will:**

1) Create a new record in the tblCurrentOrders table.

2) Create a Unique OrderNumber on the new Record.  It's usually best if you control the generation of this number and don't just let it be a system generated sequence number.  But whatever you desire is ok as long as it's Unique.

3) Set your ReleasedFlag to false on the new tblCurrentOrders record.

4) Make sure your ReleasedTimeStamp is null.  (Or whatever value you want it to be.)

5) You may want a CreatedTimeStamp which you can populate with a date of `Now()`.

6) Populate any other "Initalization" fields that need to be filled.  (Like Backorder status, Return flags, Shorted Flags, etc. etc. etc.)

7) Create a new record in the tblPlanner table.

8) Copy the Unique OrderNumber that you created for the tblCurrentOrders record into the OrderNumber field on the new tblPlanner record. This creates a link for you to use with your subqueries and subforms.

9) Now you can open the Order Form with this new OrderNumber.

**Step C: When you press the Command Button to open a set of records which are "New Orders" only:**

The Command Button needs to launch a query to find "...*tblCurrentOrders that shows only the records **without** corresponding entries in tblPlanner (new orders)*":
You just need to select tblCurrentOrders that have a ReleasedFlag set to false.

```
`SELECT * FROM tblCurrentOrders WHERE ReleasedFlag = false`
```

So when you say: "...*and then I want to be able to enter the tblPlanner info in a subform*"... you can create a subform linking to tblPlanner based on the tblCurrentOrders OrderNumber field.

This is all reliant on you observing that when you say "*...records **without** corresponding entries in tblPlanner...*" That you really mean: records **without** **released** entries in tblPlanner.  And that means: in order for a record to exist in tblCurrentOrders, it has to have a corresponding blank (or starter) record created in tblPlanner.  Thus now you can display blank tblPlanner records that are linked to unreleased tblCurrentOrders records.

Then once your data entry people are done monkeying around with the New Order, they can "Release" the order (usually by clicking on a Release Command Button).  At that point, you can set your ReleasedTimeStamp to `Now()` and set your ReleasedFlag to True in the tblCurrentOrders.  It's officially no longer a "new order" and is now a live order in your system.

You are at the tip of the iceberg for creating a home grown order entry system.  The complexities for building a good one are immense. Best of luck figuring it all out.  Just remember to use time stamps and ID fields so you can go back and un-do what may have been done by accident.

Hope this all helps. :)

Comment: This is very informative and I appreciate the help immensely.  I think I want to go the simple route (create your OrderNumber in the tblPlanner when you start a new order. Then add a flag and timestamp as to whether it's "released" yet), so can you explain a couple of the concepts you mentioned in a little more detail.

Comment: I suppose you need more detail about the details I need ;)  Can you explain what you mean by "create your OrderNumber in the tblPlanner when you start a new order"?  The two tables are linked in a one-to-one relationship using the OnderNumber field in each table.  Also, to which table do I add the timestamp and flag?

Comment: Ok... I edited the above Answer to include the new info you provided and to answer your new questions.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I will use this method with the rest of the process, as well!  Thanks!!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)  Although, clicking the check box to "accept" my answer will help me get my "Tenacious" badge for non-upvoted accepted answers.  If you could spare a click that is. :)